# VB.net Integer and Short conversion, GetMessagePos()

Tags: vb.net, winapi, c#-to-vb.net, twain

I am trying to use [DWORD WINAPI GetMessagePos(void)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938(v=vs.85).aspx) function in VB.net.

The function returns a DWORD (32 bit) which can be stored in a VB.net integer variable. A quote from the MSDN doc:

> The x-coordinate is in the low-order short of the return value; the
>   y-coordinate is in the high-order short (both represent signed values
>   because they can take negative values on systems with multiple
>   monitors)

How can I retrieve x and y coordinates using vb.net?

I am currently trying

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetMessagePos() As Integer
End Function
Sub test()
    Dim pos As Integer = GetMessagePos()

    Try
        Dim x As Short = CShort(pos And &HFFFF)
        Dim y As Short = CShort(pos >> 16)

        MessageBox.Show(x & ", " & y)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

but I am not sure if it is the right way to do it. I am trying to do some tests like

```
    Try
        Dim x As Short = -1
        Dim y As Short = 1

        Dim i As Int32 = (y << 16) Or x

        Dim x2 As Short = CShort(i And &HFFFF)
        Dim y2 As Short = CShort(i >> 16)

        MessageBox.Show(x & ", " & y)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Basically I code x and y coordinates in Short (Int16) variables, put them together in a Int32 and then try to decode.
But it doesn't seem to work since it leads to an overflow.

Any ideas of how to decode the x-y coordinates from the `GetMessagePos()` WINAPI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful when you extract these values in order to ensure that they work properly on a multiple monitor system. The "standard" way of doing it, in terms of what you would normally use with the `GetMessagePos` function are the [`GET_X_LPARAM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632654.aspx) and [`GET_Y_LPARAM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632655.aspx) macros, defined in the Windows SDK headers. These are mentioned specifically in the [`GetMessagePos` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx), and there should be similar references in all documentation for functions that return packed coordinates. There is also a warning not to use the classic `LOWORD` or `HIWORD` macros because they treat the values as unsigned quantities, as you alluded to in the question.

So, the task is essentially to translate the `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` macros from C to VB.NET. Translating them to C# is relatively simple because you can take advantage of the `unchecked` keyword:

```
int GetXValue(UInt32 lParam)
{
    return unchecked((short)(long)lParam);
}

int GetYValue(UInt32 lParam)
{
    return unchecked((short)((long)lParam >> 16));
}
```

But VB.NET doesn't have an equivalent for C#'s `unchecked` keyword, so you have to find some other way to avoid overflow. Personally, I write this kind of interop code in C# and stick it in a library so I can do what I find the most readable.

If you prefer to stick with VB.NET, there are a couple of ways to do it. The simplest conceptually is to manipulate the value as a `UInt32` to avoid the overflow. For the x-coordinate in the lower bits, you will need to explicitly mask off the upper bits to avoid an overflow. For the y-coordinate, you'll need to shift and mask. Then you can convert back to a `Short`:

```
Public Function GetXValue(lParam As UInt32) As Short
    Return CShort(lParam And &HFFFF)
End Function

Public Function GetYValue(lParam As UInt32) As Short
    Return CShort((lParam >> 16) And &HFFFF)
End Function
```

Another alternative is a bit more clever, perhaps *too* clever, but probably more efficient. It involves declaring the equivalent of a C-style union, which in VB.NET terms is just a Structure whose fields overlap:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
Public Structure CoordUnion

    <FieldOffset(0)> Public LParam As UInt32
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public XCoord As Short
    <FieldOffset(2)> Public YCoord As Short

    Public Sub New(lParam As UInt32)
        LParam = lParam
    End Sub

End Structure
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Dim temp As CoordUnion = New CoordUnion(GetMessagePos())
Dim pt As Point = New Point(temp.XCoord, temp.YCoord)
' ...
```

Note, also, that I've implicitly changed the P/Invoke signature for `GetMessagePos` so that it returns a `UInt32`:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetMessagePos() As UInt32
End Function
```

You could have just as easily used the `IntPtr` type throughout all of these helper/conversion functions as the `UInt32` type. In fact, that's how you would normally write it, since you usually get these pointer coordinates packed into an `lParam` value as part of a window message (*e.g.*, when overriding the `WndProc` method of a control).

Comment: I just tested this using an online VB.NET compiler, and it does work. Starting with 65537 as the input, I get coordinates of (-1, 1) as expected. Your test code in the question that builds `i` will still generate an arithmetic overflow, so I just built it in my head. :-)